# PowerShell - Set IIS 7.5 FTP Site to 'Allow SSL connections'

Tags: ssl, ftp, powershell, iis-7.5

Using PowerShell, how can I script the setting of an IIS 7.5 site to 'Allow SSL connections' rather than 'Require SSL connections'? I cannot seem to identify the name of the configuration property I need to modify.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would really love it if there was actually documentation available on some of this stuff. I figured it out via multiple calls to `Get-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\sitename`.

```
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\cdn -Name ftpServer.security.ssl.controlChannelPolicy -Value 0
Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\cdn -Name ftpServer.security.ssl.dataChannelPolicy -Value 0
```